# Конфликт wi-fi интерфейса

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

На ноутбуке установлена `Linux agregat 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u3`, интернет поднят через ETH-интерфейс, дрова на wi-fi не ставил. В процессе работы система зависает. Событийных логов не нашел, но заинтересовал вот этот кусок `/var/log/user.log`:

```
Jul 22 19:16:49 agregat lightdm[934]: Error getting user list from   
org.freedesktop.Accounts:    
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name   
org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files  
Jul 22 19:16:52 agregat org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1006]: SpiRegistry   
daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry  
Jul 22 19:20:58 agregat NetworkManager[482]: <info>  [1563812458.1174] 
device   (wlo1): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to B6:4D:7A:DE:5E:2C 
(scanning)  
Jul 22 19:21:28 agregat NetworkManager[482]: <info>  [1563812488.2758] 
device   (wlo1): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disabled  
Jul 22 19:21:28 agregat NetworkManager[482]: <info>  [1563812488.3260] 
device   (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disabled -> inactive
```

При выполнение `ip addr show` настройки `wlo1` такие:

```
wlo1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 56:5c:85:79:b3:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

В чем может быть проблема, коллеги?

Comment: если не считать проблемой само наличие network-manager-а, то никаких других проблем в приведённой вами информации не наблюдается.

Comment: Александр, можно конкретики? Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Приведенная информация не даёт никаких намёков на описанную проблему.